# Count and sum numbers by name

Tags: python

I'm looking to count the number of invoices that are only consecutive. I tried converting datetime to string then counting with the below code but I think i'm making it too complicated. Any suggestions?

```
date_strs = df['Invoice Date']
df.dropna(how='all')

dates = [datetime.strptime(str(d, "%m-%d-%Y")) for d in date_strs]

date_ints = set([d.toordinal() for d in dates])

if len(date_ints) == 1:
    print("unique")
elif max(date_ints) - min(date_ints) == len(date_ints) - 1:
    print("consecutive")
else:
    print ("not consecutive")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Vender ID': {0: 8555, 1: 8555, 2: 8555, 3: 1044, 4: 1044, 5: 1044, 6: 1044},
 'Vendor Name': {0: 'Macys',
  1: 'Macys',
  2: 'Macys',
  3: 'JCPenny',
  4: 'JCPenny',
  5: 'JCPenny',
  6: 'JCPenny'},
 'Invoice Date': {0: '1/1/2020',
  1: '1/2/2020',
  2: '1/3/2020',
  3: '2/1/2020',
  4: '2/2/2020',
  5: '2/3/2020',
  6: '2/5/2020'},
 'Invoice Number': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# fix time format
df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'])

# auxillary column to find sequences
df = df.sort_values(['Vender ID', 'Vendor Name', 'Invoice Date'])
df['continue'] = df['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()

# find time sequences
val_count = df['continue'].value_counts()
val_count = val_count[val_count.gt(1)].index.tolist()

# filter and group by Vendor
df[df['continue'].isin(val_count)].groupby(['Vendor Name'])['Vendor Name'].count()

# Vendor Name
# JCPenny    3
# Macys      3
```

Comment: I like this approach...Thank you. How would I go about counting if the invoice date is the same between two different invoices?

Comment: Also, what does .dt.days.ne(1).cumsum() do?

Comment: @Meowzz, `df['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1)` reads like this: get the difference in days between rows, return True if they are exactly 1 day. Then cumsum will sum the values, essentially returning a unique group ID. If you want to know more, execute them step by step in the above example. To also include 0 day differences you can change it to `df['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1)` to `(~df['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.isin([0, 1])).cumsum()`